# Adding Column value from Previous Row based on Where Condition.

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with symbol, epoch and Volume. The epoch is stored based on Symbol and Epoch in ascending order.

[image]

I want to get cumulative volume which is sum of volume and prev timestamp and the volume at current timestamp for the same day and for same symbol.

[image]

I am new to SQL and this already seems to be quite complicated. Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using over clause.
[Over Clause Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql)

```
Select Symbol,
       Epoch,
       Volume,
       Sum(Volume)Over(Partition by Symbol,Substring(Epoch,1,6) Order by Epoch) AS CuVol
From YourTableName
```